# Match specific string not preceded with a word and any amount of whitespaces using .NET regex

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am using

Regex: `(?<!WHEN\s)EMP_ID`

Query: `SELECT EMP_ID, CASE WHEN EMP_ID > 115 THEN 'greater' WHEN EMP_ID < 115 THEN 'lower' END AS TEST`

Matches: 1 match ( EMP_ID)

But if I add any spaces after WHEN in this query, then it will show 2 matches of 'EMP_ID', which is wrong.
Or if I use the where condition in my query and use this column name then also it will give me 2 matches of the column name.

**How to correct this regex or use a different method to solve this issue in C#?**

Comment: Use `(?<!WHEN\s+)EMP_ID`

Comment: _"How to correct this regex or use a different method to solve this issue in C#?"_ - you can't: SQL `SELECT` clauses can contain arbitrary nested sub-expressions and queries, [it is not mathetically possible for a regex to handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) those situations. You will need to use a SQL parser library (Microsoft has one for T-SQL in  SQL Server's`SMO` library which (I believe, but can't prove) is built from the same Antlr sources as SQL Server's own parser): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!WHEN\s+)EMP_ID
```

Or, with whole word matching:

```
\b(?<!\bWHEN\s+)EMP_ID\b
```

See the [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4xAzTM/1).

Since .NET regex flavor allows unknown length patterns inside lookbehinds, the `(?<!WHEN\s+)` works and fails any location that is immediately preceded with `WHEN` + one or more whitespaces.

Comment: @Dai You have different requirements from OP. OP's requirement is to match one occurrence of `EMP_ID` in the given string. Nowhere is it written `TEST` must be matched.

Comment: _"I want to get the column names in the SQL query"_ - they said "column names".

Comment: @Dai Read the question, it is about the issue where the regex cannot properly match a string not preceded with a word followed with any amount of whitespaces. Not about matching any column names.

Comment: Nice of you to remove the exact quote I copied from the OP's question...

Comment: @Dai Because it was not the point of the whole question. I just adjusted the title and problem statement to the problem described in the body of the question.

Comment: It's not for you to derive the author's intent, they haven't even posted any clarifying comments yet; it's bad form for you to unilaterally edit their post to remove content and context without their consent - you never even asked them.

Comment: There is nothing to clarify, the question is clear to me, and we must help people by editing the titles to match the real question body.

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel both of you are correct in some way. Still thanks for the help